# How to cache google cloud storage (GCS) with cloudflare?

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, cdn, cloudflare

How can I cache assets stored on google cloud storage (GCS)? I've been trying to make it work in the past 2 days with no luck. My website have backend & frontend, and the asset is stored on GCS. I tried the following guide:

a. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-Cloudflare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-

b. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

c. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-dynamic

Let say my website is example.com, here's what I did:

1. I created a bucket on GCS "img.example.com"
2. On Cloudflare I set CNAME with the following: 
   Name: img.example.com 
   Value: c.storage.googleapis.com
3. I set all object in GCS bucket 'readable by public' (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets)

The image is still not cached by Cloudflare and the header status still not showing CF-Status. Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us the real value of `img.example.com`?  The problem is not readily apparent from the description, which sounds like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the link from https://storage.googlesapis.com/subdomain.mysite.com/... to https://subdomain.mysite.com/... (simply removing "storage.googleapis.com") and it works! 
Hope it helps other that stuck as well.