# Cloudflare CDN for Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, cdn, cloudflare, google-cloud-cdn

I have a custom domain (cdnexample.com) and a Firebase Google Cloud Storage Bucket (examplefiles.appspot.com).
I want to configure cdnexample.com domain in Cloudflare CDN to source from GCS bucket (examplefiles.appspot.com).

For example, given a GCS File: https://storage.googleapis.com/examplefiles.appspot.com/image1.jpg I want to get the Cloudflare CDN File working: https://cdnexample.com/image1.jpg

The problem is that I **cannot** change the GCS bucket name (examplefiles.appspot.com) to match my Cloudflare domain name (cdnexample.com). All the solutions I came across below require the GCS bucket name to match Cloudflare domain name and use CNAME configuration with `c.storage.googleapis.com`.

I have read through the following relevant articles:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints
- https://devopsdirective.com/posts/2020/10/gcs-cloudflare-hosting/
- https://community.cloudflare.com/t/using-cloudflare-cdn-https-with-google-cloud-storage/15602
- [How to cache google cloud storage (GCS) with cloudflare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518743/how-to-cache-google-cloud-storage-gcs-with-cloudflare)
- [Using Cloudflare CDN + HTTPS with Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762212/using-cloudflare-cdn-https-with-google-cloud-storage)
- [Use CloudFlare to CDN a Google Cloud Storage Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116278/use-cloudflare-to-cdn-a-google-cloud-storage-bucket)
- https://medium.com/@pablo.delvalle.cr/cloudflare-and-google-cloud-for-hosting-a-static-site-fd2e1a97aa9b

Does anyone have an idea of how to make the Cloudflare CDN work in this case?

Comment: 1) Create a new bucket and move the files. 2) Create an Google HTTPS load balancer with a custom domain.

Comment: Thanks John. I would love to go with 2) approach with load balancer. Do you mind providing more details?

Comment: Let me know if this helps get you started: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets

Comment: Thanks John!
- Should the custom domain in load balance be the same as the Cloudflare domain?
- Should I also enable Google Cloud CDN as well?

Comment: Review this link: https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/cdn-interconnect

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can set up a load balancer with backend bucket which will connect your storage bucket and can be accessed with an IP address, later you point the IP address in your custom domain. you can find the below information about adding a backend bucket [here](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-bucket)