# Using a private google cloud storage with a custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I have an google cloud storage buckets and one rails app to access this buckets. My app works with files from 1M until 300M in uploads/downloads.
On my rails app I use carriewave gem, so ...all the throughput comes to my app, after to the bucket....until now, everything normal.

Recently I implement [GCP direct upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-forms) but, the base url is storage.googleapis.com. This is terrible for my customers that have such a high level security in their local networks.

I need that storage.googleapis.com becomes storage.mycustomdomain.com. In this approach my customers will just allow *.mycustomdomain.com in their networks.

Someone could help me?
Tnks

Comment: 1) Neither of your problems/goals provides for good security. There is nothing wrong with using **storage.googleapis.com**. Using your own domain does not enhance security. **Allowing users to POST to cloud storage is a security risk**. You are focusing on the wrong security problem. 2) To use your own domain name you have several options. a) Use a static website https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website b) deploy a CDN with your domain name https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/doc/how-to-set-up-a-custom-domain-cdn-for-google-cloud-storage/

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage public objects are served directly from GCP through `storage.googleapis.com`, as explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data). From John Hanley’s comment, and according to this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website), Cloud Storage does not directly support custom domains:

> Because Cloud Storage doesn't support custom domains with HTTPS on its own, this tutorial uses Cloud Storage with HTTP(S) Load Balancing to serve content from a custom domain over HTTPS.

The guide goes into creating a load balancer service which you can use to serve user content from your own domain, using the buckets as the service backend. Otherwise, it is also [possible](https://medium.com/@marco_37432/create-a-custom-domain-cdn-with-google-beta-7ad9531dfbae) to create a CDN which is supported by Cloud Storage and uses a custom domain, as mentioned by the blog objectives:

- I want to serve images on my website (comparison for contact lenses) from a cloud bucket.
- I want to serve it from my domain, cdn.kontaktlinsen-preisvergleich.de
- I need HTTPS for that domain, because my website uses HTTPS everywhere and I don’t want to mix that.

This related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65241413/) also mentions implementation of a CDN to use a custom domain to serve Cloud Storage objects.